# Is there any way by which I can upload a local image in a google doc file using the google docs API?

Tags: python, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am working on a project that would generate documents(relieving letter,experience letter etc ) for an individual whenever he/she demands it, after the document is generated it's link would be mailed to admin to approve/reject the document, if the admin approves the document, a picture of an electronic signature is placed at the end of document and would be further processed, the problem here is that I am providing the photo of the electronic signature through the google drive shareable link which has to be accessible by public, which is'nt secure, is there any secure way by which it can be done(Probably uploading the image from the local server) ?

I've been reading the API documentation of google docs but could not find a suitable method

```
    requests = [{
        'insertInlineImage': {

            'uri':
            'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1wwQJq4LBe2r-zgZk0PdLW7GIlImvIxsG', #this is the google drive link for the signature png file
            'objectSize': {
                'height': {
                    'magnitude': 200,
                    'unit': 'PT'
                },
                'width': {
                    'magnitude': 150,
                    'unit': 'PT'
                }
            },

            "endOfSegmentLocation": {

            }
        }
    }]

    body = {'requests': requests}
    response = service.documents().batchUpdate(
        documentId=document_id, body=body).execute()
    insert_inline_image_response = response.get(
        'replies')[0].get('insertInlineImage')
```